# Поиск нужного родителя

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Имеется блок класса `content`, внутри которого располагаются ссылки, текстовые поля и прочее... Мне нужно проверить, если пользователь нажал вне этого блока, то блок `content` скрыть. Как лучше проверить, является ли нажатый элемент дочерним для `content`, и если является, то получить `id` блока родителя (с классом `content`) и скрыть его по `id`.

```
 <div class="content" id="2">
     <>
        ..
        ...
         <>

        </>
     </>

 </div>
```

Получаю нажатый элемент js:

```
$('body').click( function() {  
clickedElement=event.target||event.srcElement;  
});
```

Вопрос несколько изменился: у меня на страничке несколько сущностей, внизу каждой из которых ссылка "комментировать". Если нажимаю на ссылку, то всплывает div  с полем для ввода комментария и прочим. Так вот, если после появления этого дива, нажимаем вне его, то он сворачивается... я написал вот так(должно быть это быдло):

```
$('body').click( function() {
    clickedElement=event.target||event.srcElement;
    if(isCommentElement(clickedElement)) $('.comment-block').hide();
    function isCommentElement(currentElement){
        while (currentElement) {
            if ($(currentElement).attr('class') != 'comment-block') return true;
            else currentElement = currentElement.parentNode;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Но это не работает, потому что когда мы нажимаем на "Комментировать", срабатывает всплывание и сразу же мгновенно за ним проверяется нажато ли внутри блока с комментом, а так как ссылка "комментировать" вне его, он сразу же сварачивается обратно...помогите как разрешить?

Исправил на

```
if ($(currentElement).attr('class') != 'comment-block' && $(currentElement).attr('class') != 'comment-link') return true;
```

Все равно не работает(

Comment: >когда мы нажимаем на "Комментировать", срабатывает всплывание

добавьте в обработчик клика по ссылке `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Я воспользовался вариантом, который ниже. Он работает корректно, причём даже без обработки события нажатия ссылки. Спасибо

Comment: у вас же есть обработчик, который вызывает всплывающий блок для ввода комментария, вот туда и добавьте *в начало*

Comment: $(".comment-link").click(function(event) {
 id = '#comment-text_' + ($(this).attr('id'));
  $(id).show("slide");
  event.stopPropagation();
 });

Верно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по вашему js используется jquery. В этом случае можно написать следующую функцию

```
$('body').click(function(event){
  var block = $(event.target).closest('.content'); 
  if(block.length){// 0 если вне блока нажали и 1 если внутри блока
     block.eq(0).hide(); //прятать можно любым удобным способом 
  }
})
```